# Is it possible to send a BBM message thru the blackberry API?

Tags: java, blackberry, jde

Is it possible to send a BBM message thru the blackberry API?

Answer (score 2):

They have a [BBM SDK](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25690/Overview_1323631_11.jsp), you might want to look into that.